# Where are the docker daemon logs stored on ubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, systemd

I expected to find the logs in `/var/log/upstart` or `/var/lib/docker` but had no such luck. I'm trying to debug a docker-compose issue and it'd be extremely helpful to know what API calls are being made behind the scenes.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is systemd and not upstart. You can view logs with `docker` commands or `systemd` commands like `journalctl`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't directly relate to programming. It be appropriate on the Ask Ubuntu or Unix & Linux StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 7):

You can check these places:

- `journalctl -u docker` for docker logs in the systemd journal
- `journalctl | grep docker` for system logs that mention docker
- `docker logs CONTAINER` for logs of a container named CONTAINER

Comment: Although useful, this doesn't answer the question. Where are they stored?

Answer (score 5):

And to tail it you can use the following :

```
journalctl -u docker -n -f
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question.  It should be added as a comment against the question.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation.